# Reactの子コンポーネントに親コンポーネントでuseStateで生成された値をPropsに渡した時の再描画について

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React の useStateで生成されたstate（`newOrTotal`)を子コンポーネントに渡して、setNewOrTotalで更新した時に`<div>{newOrTotal}</div>`は更新されるのに子コンポーネント`<Chart>`が更新されません。どうしたら更新されるのか。
ご教示願えませんでしょうか。

`const [newOrTotal, setNewOrTotal] = useState(1);`

```
<Chart
  key={data.id}
  id={data.id}
  group={data.group}
  newOrTotal={newOrTotal}
/>
```

``

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Card, ToggleButtonGroup, ToggleButton } from 'react-bootstrap';

import { useApp } from '../context'
import { Chart } from "./Chart";
import { ChartPrefecture } from "./ChartPrefecture";

// 引数にタイトル、エレメントIDを持つようにする
export const CardOriginal = ({ data }) => {
    // new: 1, total: 2
    const [newOrTotal, setNewOrTotal] = useState(1);
    const {state, statePrefectureGraph} = useApp();
    // 累計
    const getTotal = () => {
        let total = 0;
        let dayBeforeRatio = 0;
        if(data.group == 1 && 
            state[data.id] &&
            state[data.id].total) {
            total = state[data.id].total;
            dayBeforeRatio = state[data.id].dayBeforeRatio;
        }
        if(data.group == 2 &&
            statePrefectureGraph[state.prefId] &&
            statePrefectureGraph[state.prefId][data.id] && 
            statePrefectureGraph[state.prefId][data.id].total) {
            total = statePrefectureGraph[state.prefId][data.id].total;
            dayBeforeRatio = statePrefectureGraph[state.prefId][data.id].dayBeforeRatio;
        }
        // 小数点２桁まで
        if(!Number.isInteger(total)) total = total.toFixed(2);
        if(!Number.isInteger(dayBeforeRatio)) dayBeforeRatio = dayBeforeRatio.toFixed(2);
        return {total, dayBeforeRatio};
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        let unmounted = false;
        //アンマウントされていなければステートを更新
        if(!unmounted) {
            console.log('newOrTotal: ', newOrTotal)
            console.log('data.id: ', data.id)
        }
        //クリーンアップ関数を返す
        return () => { unmounted = true; };
    }, [newOrTotal]);

    const toggleOnChange = () => {
        if(newOrTotal == 1) setNewOrTotal(2);
        if(newOrTotal == 2) setNewOrTotal(1);
    }

    return (        
        <Card>
          <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>
              {data.group == 1 ? (data.title) : (`${state.prefJa}の${data.title}`)}
              </Card.Title>
              <Card.Subtitle>
                9月6日時点
              </Card.Subtitle>
              <Card.Text className='float-right total'>
                  累計<span>{getTotal().total}</span>
              </Card.Text>
              <br />
              <Card.Text className='float-right day-before-ratio'>
                  前日比{getTotal().dayBeforeRatio}
              </Card.Text>
              <div>{newOrTotal}</div>
              <div className='btn-wwrapper'>
                <div className='btn-wrapper'>
                    <ToggleButtonGroup 
                        type='radio'
                        name='xxx'
                        defaultValue={1}
                        onChange={toggleOnChange}
                    >
                      <ToggleButton 
                        value={1}
                        className='btn-sm'
                      >
                        新規
                      </ToggleButton>
                      <ToggleButton 
                        value={2}
                        className='btn-sm'
                      >
                        累計
                      </ToggleButton>
                    </ToggleButtonGroup>
                </div>
              </div>
              {data.group == 1 ? 
                (<Chart
                  key={`chart_xxx_${data.id}_${data.group}`}
                  id={data.id}
                  group={data.group}
                  newOrTotal={newOrTotal}
                />) :
                (<ChartPrefecture
                  id={data.id}
                  group={data.group}
                />)
              }           
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>     
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Chart`の実装を見てみないと正確な助言はできませんが、`Chart`の中で`newOrTotal`を改めて`useState`に放り込んでいないでしょうか？

純粋なpropsとして親から子に渡さないと更新されない状況にお見受けします。